# Scala Spark - split vector column into separate columns in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, countvectorizer

I have a Spark DataFrame where I have a column with Vector values. The vector values are all n-dimensional, aka with the same length. I also have a list of column names `Array("f1", "f2", "f3", ..., "fn")`, each corresponds to one element in the vector.

```
some_columns... | Features
      ...       | [0,1,0,..., 0]

to

some_columns... | f1 | f2 | f3 | ... | fn

      ...       | 0  | 1  | 0  | ... | 0
```

What is the best way to achieve this? I thought of one way which is to create a new DataFrame with `createDataFrame(Row(Features), featureNameList)` and then join with the old one, but it requires spark context to use createDataFrame. I only want to transform the existing data frame. I also know `.withColumn("fi", value)` but what do I do if `n` is large?

I'm new to Scala and Spark and couldn't find any good examples for this. I think this can be a common task. My particular case is that I used the `CountVectorizer` and wanted to recover each column individually for better readability instead of only having the vector result.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way could be to convert the `vector` column to an `array<double>` and then using `getItem` to extract individual elements.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.ml._

val df = Seq( (1 , linalg.Vectors.dense(1,0,1,1,0) ) ).toDF("id", "features")
//df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, features: vector]

df.show
//+---+---------------------+
//|id |features             |
//+---+---------------------+
//|1  |[1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0]|
//+---+---------------------+

// A UDF to convert VectorUDT to ArrayType
val vecToArray = udf( (xs: linalg.Vector) => xs.toArray )

// Add a ArrayType Column   
val dfArr = df.withColumn("featuresArr" , vecToArray($"features") )

// Array of element names that need to be fetched
// ArrayIndexOutOfBounds is not checked.
// sizeof `elements` should be equal to the number of entries in column `features`
val elements = Array("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5")

// Create a SQL-like expression using the array 
val sqlExpr = elements.zipWithIndex.map{ case (alias, idx) => col("featuresArr").getItem(idx).as(alias) }

// Extract Elements from dfArr    
dfArr.select(sqlExpr : _*).show
//+---+---+---+---+---+
//| f1| f2| f3| f4| f5|
//+---+---+---+---+---+
//|1.0|0.0|1.0|1.0|0.0|
//+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is really helpful. Could you please add the last step where the original df gets the new individual columns, aka producing the df with `id` (actually not just `id`, should be all other existing columns) and `f1, f2... ` columns together. That way the df is modified in-place. This may be obvious to you but I want to learn the right approach since I'm not quite familiar with Scala yet.

Comment: You can use `dfArr.select( (col("id") +: sqlExpr) :_*).show(false)` This will prepend the column `id` into the `sqlExpr` Array and then pass it to the `select` function. Also, keep in mind that no in-place changes are happening. `dfArr.select( (col("id") +: sqlExpr) :_*)` will return you a new dataframe. `df` will still have the original contents since dataframes are immutable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I also realized there should be no in-place changes.

Comment: A self-note for completeness: for adding all previous columns, `dfArr.select( (col("*") +: sqlExpr) :_*)`