# Converting from vector column to Double[Array] column in scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame doubleSeq whose structure is as below

```
res274: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [finalFeatures: vector]
```

The first record of the column is as follows

```
res281: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [[3.0,6.0,-0.7876947819954485,-0.21757635218517163,0.9731844373162398,-0.6641741696340383,-0.6860072219935377,-0.2990737363481845,-0.7075863760365155,0.8188108975549018,-0.8468559840943759,-0.04349947247406488,-0.45236764452589984,1.0333959313820456,0.6097566070878347,-0.7106619551471779,-0.7750330808435969,-0.08097610412658443,-0.45338437108038904,-0.2952869863393396,-0.30959772365257004,0.6988768123463287,0.17049117199049213,3.2674649019757385,-0.8333373234944124,1.8462942520757128,-0.49441222531240125,-0.44187299748074166,-0.300810826687287]]
```

I want to extract the double array

```
[3.0,6.0,-0.7876947819954485,-0.21757635218517163,0.9731844373162398,-0.6641741696340383,-0.6860072219935377,-0.2990737363481845,-0.7075863760365155,0.8188108975549018,-0.8468559840943759,-0.04349947247406488,-0.45236764452589984,1.0333959313820456,0.6097566070878347,-0.7106619551471779,-0.7750330808435969,-0.08097610412658443,-0.45338437108038904,-0.2952869863393396,-0.30959772365257004,0.6988768123463287,0.17049117199049213,3.2674649019757385,-0.8333373234944124,1.8462942520757128,-0.49441222531240125,-0.44187299748074166,-0.300810826687287]
```

from this -

```
doubleSeq.head(1)(0)(0)
```

gives

```
Any = [3.0,6.0,-0.7876947819954485,-0.21757635218517163,0.9731844373162398,-0.6641741696340383,-0.6860072219935377,-0.2990737363481845,-0.7075863760365155,0.8188108975549018,-0.8468559840943759,-0.04349947247406488,-0.45236764452589984,1.0333959313820456,0.6097566070878347,-0.7106619551471779,-0.7750330808435969,-0.08097610412658443,-0.45338437108038904,-0.2952869863393396,-0.30959772365257004,0.6988768123463287,0.17049117199049213,3.2674649019757385,-0.8333373234944124,1.8462942520757128,-0.49441222531240125,-0.44187299748074166,-0.300810826687287]
```

Which is not solving my problem

[Scala Spark - split vector column into separate columns in a Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911608/scala-spark-split-vector-column-into-separate-columns-in-a-spark-dataframe)

Is not solving my issue but its an indicator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to extract a Vector from a Row, and turn it into an array of doubles.

The problem with your code is that the `get` method (and the implicit `apply` method you are using) returns an object of type `Any`. Indeed, a `Row` is a generic, unparametrized object and there is no way to now at compile time what types it contains. It's a bit like Lists in java 1.4 and before. To solve it in spark, you can use the `getAs` method that you can parametrize with a type of your choosing.

In your situation, you seem to have a dataframe containing a vector (`org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector`).

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg._
val firstRow = df.head(1)(0) // or simply df.head
val vect : Vector = firstRow.getAs[Vector](0)
// or all in one: df.head.getAs[Vector](0)

// to transform into a regular array
val array : Array[Double] = vect.toArray
```

Note also that you can access columns by name like this:

```scala
val vect : Vector = firstRow.getAs[Vector]("finalFeatures")
```

Comment: How do i convert from wrapped array to normal double array ?

Comment: `.toArray`, I edited the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: value getAs is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame -> which import statement are you using ?

Comment: It's a method of Row, not dataframe

Comment: I am getting an error : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq
  ... 54 elided

Comment: Error for this code : import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors 
result.select("finalFeatures").head(1)(0).getAs[Seq[Double]](0)

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you give me the result of `dataframe.printSchema`?

Comment: root
 |-- finalFeatures: vector (nullable = true)

Comment: I edited my answer to take into account all this. It should work fine now ;)

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
  ... 76 elided ..sorry i get this error ...are there two errors here ?

Comment: try `getAs[DenseVector]` then... but I'm surprised this does not work... It could be interesting that you add in your question more information about how you generated this dataframe.

Comment: I created this dataframe using vector assembler - The suggestion you made failed with a wierd error - import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector

Comment: It worked Oli - getAs[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector] use the full path

Comment: OK, now i know what's wrong. You're using SparkML, I googled the doc and landed on the old spark mllib. I'll fix the answer again :)

Comment: import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
var x = df.head(1)(0).getAs[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector](0).toArray
x.length - purrfect

Comment: Great :) The answer is fixed!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191443/discussion-between-leothorn-and-oli).